# how to view git notes attached to blob objects in eGIT

Tags: git, egit

I attached a git note to a **commit** object. (via CLI)
From **eGIt**, In the History View, i am able to see all notes additions (when the **Show Notes History** is enabled).

Now, i add a notes to a **blob** object. This is also visible in the history view as before when **Show In History** is invoked at the repo level. But it is not possible to identify that this is a notes entry for a file and for which file (except that it shows the file's SHA-1).
I tried my luck by invoking **Show In History** for the file, but this note entry does not show up.

How do i read file level notes explicitly from eGIt?
Also, how do i add notes to commits or blobs from eGIt?